# Passing parameters from php through button formaction from table row

Tags: php, html, clickonce

I am trying to pass two parameters to the opendirectory.php script. Its not working for me. When I click the open directory button my opendirectory.php script does not execute.

Any help much appreciated.

This is my Open Directory button definition and passing the two parameters.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
   <tr>
            <td><?=$row['projectno'];?></td>
            <td><?=$row['projectdescription'];?></td>
            <form>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" formaction="opendirectory.php?param1=<?=$row['projectno'];?>&param2=<?=$row['projectdescription'];?>">Open Directory</button></td>
            </form>
    </tr>
<?php
}
```

This is my opendirectory.php script. The opendirectory.php script calls a click once deployment application.

```
<?php
$Number = trim($_POST["param1"]);
$Description = trim($_POST["param2"]);
header( 'refresh:2; url=http://localhost/LaunchDirectory/LaunchDirectory.application?ProjNo='.$Number.'&ProjDesc='.$Description);
die();
?>
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. You cannot have a `form` nested inside the table as it is there - the form must either be wholly contained within a single table-cell or the entire table must be contained within the form

Comment: Why not simply use a hyperlink, like `<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href='opendirectory.php?param1=<?=$row['projectno'];?>&param2=<?=$row['projectdescription'];?>'>Open Directory</a>`?

Comment: Yes I repositioned my <form> tags and it works now. <td><form><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" formaction="opendirectory.php?param1=<?=$row['projectno'];?>&param2=<?=$row['projectdescription'];?>">Open Directory</button></form></td>

Comment: My opendirectory.php script  is throwing undefined index param1 and undefined index param2 when called any ideas

Comment: Your form is sending a GET request but you are looking for POST variables in your PHP.....either add form method to the forms or change the PHP to use GET

Comment: I have changed the forms method to post. <form method="post"> it does not work as above.

Comment: Doesn't work how exactly? Thst coukd mean anything. You'll need to [edit] your question to add your latest version of the code, and also be  much more specific about how it behaves

Comment: If you change the form method to POST you would need to use input elements named the same as the `param` parameters ... a querystring is still essentially a GET request. You do not really need the form if you used hyperlinks - unless it is essential that the PHP process the request using POST rather than GET

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that you could accomplish the apparent goal - perhaps the following simple demo might help show some possibilities.

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST['p1'],
        $_POST['p2'],
        $_POST['method']
    )){
        printf('<pre><h1>%s</h1>%s</pre>',$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],print_r($_POST,true));
    }
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset(
        $_GET['p1'],
        $_GET['p2'],
        $_GET['method']
    )){
        printf('<pre><h1>%s</h1>%s</pre>',$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],print_r($_GET,true));
    }
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            button,
            [type='submit'],
            [type='button']{
                margin:1rem;
                padding:1rem;
                width:180px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--
            Method 1:
            Essentially as per the question - using formaction with a querystring and form method set to POST. 
            
            Does not work!
        -->
        <form method='post'>
            <button type='submit' formaction='?p1=apple&p2=red&method=1'>View [Method 1]</button>
        </form>
        
        <!--
            Method 2:
            A regular form with hidden inputs and form method set to POST.
            
            Works!
        -->
        <form method='post'>
            <input type='hidden' name='p1' value='banana' />
            <input type='hidden' name='p2' value='yellow' />
            <input type='hidden' name='method' value='2' />
            <input type='submit' value='View [Method 2]' />
        </form>
        
        <!--
            Method 3:
            No form - parameters passed by GET request in querystring.
            PHP processes request using $_GET rather than POST.
            
            Works!
        -->
        <a href='?p1=mango&p2=green&method=3'><button>View [Method 3]</button></a>
        
        <!--
            Method 4:
            Regular form using POST method and hidden inputs.
            Multiple buttons within table ( wholly nested within form ) trigger Javascript.
            Javascript adds values to hidden inputs and submimts the form.
            
            Works!
        -->
        <form method='post'>
            <input type='hidden' name='p1' />
            <input type='hidden' name='p2' />
            <input type='hidden' name='method' value='4' />
            
            <table>
                <tr data-p1='raspberry' data-p2='purple'><td><input type='button' value='View [Method 4 - Item 1]' /></td></tr>
                <tr data-p1='peach' data-p2='orange'><td><input type='button' value='View [Method 4 - Item 2]' /></td></tr>
                <tr data-p1='kiwi' data-p2='green'><td><input type='button' value='View [Method 4 - Item 3]' /></td></tr>
            </table>
            
            <script>
                document.querySelectorAll('tr td input').forEach(bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',e=>{
                    let form=e.target.closest('table').parentNode;
                        form.p1.value=e.target.closest('tr').dataset.p1;
                        form.p2.value=e.target.closest('tr').dataset.p2;
                        form.submit();
                }))
            </script>
        </form>
        
    </body>
</html>
```